# How to include Tag names in AEM search query builder while Tag IDs are saved in the repository

Tags: aem, query-builder, sling

In AEM, how can we write a query as the default search works, where a Tag ID is saved for an asset, while the user wanted to search by the Tag Name/jcr:title?

For example, we can search for assets that has a particular Tag assigned. As below:

[image]

the way there are assigned is as follows:

[image]

And are saved in the repository as ID's.. as below:

[image]

For example, a tag hierarchy:

**TAG ID:**

```
/etc/tags/SXM/shows/entertainment/kids/8216/1073743514
```

**The TAG NAME for the above:**

```
SXM > Shows > Talk > Kids > Kids Place Live > Weird Al April
```

I tried the below but does not work?

```
type=dam:Assets
path=/content/dam/
tagsearch=SXM:Shows/Talk/Kids/Kids Place Live/Weird Al April
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible but, depending on the nature of your site, it may not be a good idea to implement this. Keep in mind that titles may not be unique, especially on a multi-language website. Unless you use tag names, you risk finding content tagged with homonyms of the tag you're actually searching for. For example, `bad` means _the opposite of good_ in English and _bath_ in German. Not saying that's the case here but using this kind of queries in a component that automatically finds content to display on a homepage could result in hilarious mistakes or even legal problems.

Comment: We are writing a custom rest service that customer want to use. They can add any  tag(s) to assets, and while searching, they wanted to find the assets that has the search term anywhere in the assets (name, desc, tag etc). And defining a taxonomy for Tags (hierarchy) is not a bad practice. Ours is not a multi-language site and i'm not sure what mistakes/issues this will cause? Moreover the same works on the default AEM search. We wanted to try to implement the same in our query.

Comment: Another example, just English this time. `polo` is a kind of shirt, a sport and a brand. Which one do you mean to find? As for multi-lingual sites, you may run into situations where you will want to search for related pages across language versions, without using the name internally, you have no way of matching `my/taxonomy:Dog` to `my/taxonomy/Hund`. If it's purely an authoring tool, then a full text search by title should be alright as someone should be able to interpret the search result. I'd still find a way to present the title to the user and use the name internally though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this and posting the answer.

There is a predicate **tagsearch** that would build the tag hierarchy to the search query.

The below worked for me:

```
type=dam:Assets  
path=/content/dam/  
tagsearch=Weird Al April
```

or

```
type=dam:Assets   
path=/content/dam/  
tagsearch=Kids Place Live
```

or

```
type=dam:Assets  
path=/content/dam/  
tagsearch=Kids
```

[image]